# chrome loads from cache memory while reloading the web pages

Tags: windows, html, css, google-chrome, web

As I am a web-developer my work reley on web browsers . 
I edited html and css files to get the exact result I want in the web design but from very starting chrome loads from its chache memory , You  know chromium also do the same thing . It become very difficult for me check each time I have to change the URL in order to reload the web page to check the changes I have made on the page. While on the firefox and edge its all great up to time , please tell me the solution how can I remove this setting of loading from chache in chrome , 
I use windows 7 and 10 on my laptop 
currently using chrome -Version 57.0.2987.133

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable chrome caching : 
check out this : 
[Disabling Chrome cache for website development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development)

or you can install Clear Cash extension from google chrome extensions

Answer (score 0):

The Chrome DevTools can disable the cache.

F12 or Right-click and Inspect Element to open the DevTools. Now click Network in the toolbar. Finally, check the Disable cache checkbox at the top.